# Angular 6 - jsPDF -autotable - PDF not generating properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I don't know where am doing wrong(in loop). Currently, pdf is generating with 1st property of the 1st object only. Header is also not displaying. trying to load json response in jsbpdf autoTable. for time being, pls consider below mock data.

So far,

**test.ts**

```
prepareDoc(){

  const header = [['Devloper ID', 'Develoepr Name', 'Department', 'Location', 'Rate(Hr)', 'Current Status', 'Contact']];

    const data = [{
          'id': 'xxx-001',
          'dev_name': 'qqqqq',
          'department': 'ABC',
          'loc': 'loc-001',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Open',
          'contact': '--'
        }, {
          'id': 'xxx-002',
          'dev_name': 'eeeee',
          'department': 'DEF',
          'loc': 'loc-002',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Engaged',
          'contact': '--'
        }, {
          'id': 'xxx-003',
          'dev_name': 'rrrrr',
          'department': 'IJK',
          'loc': 'loc-003',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Qued(5)',
          'contact': '--'
        }, {
          'id': 'xxx-004',
          'dev_name': 'bbbbb',
          'department': 'LMN',
          'loc': 'loc-004',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Vacction',
          'contact': '--'
        }];

        data.forEach(elm => {
           const temp = [elm.id, elm.dev_name, elm.department, elm.loc, elm.hourly_rate, elm.current_Status, elm.contact];
           rows.push(temp);
           console.log('Rows', rows); // showing all data
         });

        downloadPDF.autoTable(header, rows);
        downloadPDF.save('demo.pdf');
}
```

html

```
<button (click)='prepareDoc()'></button>
```

**issue**

PFA: pdf generating without header and other data

[image: pdf generating witout header and other data]

Pls some help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use autoTable method like this:

```
downloadPDF.autoTable({
              head: header,
              body: rows,
            });
```

It works good for me. I checked it with this code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqvqVX:

```
const downloadPDF = new jsPDF();
function prepareDoc() {
  const header = [['Devloper ID', 'Develoepr Name', 'Department', 'Location', 'Rate(Hr)', 'Current Status', 'Contact']];
const rows=[];
    const data = [{
          'id': 'xxx-001',
          'dev_name': 'qqqqq',
          'department': 'ABC',
          'loc': 'loc-001',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Open',
          'contact': '--'
        }, {
          'id': 'xxx-002',
          'dev_name': 'eeeee',
          'department': 'DEF',
          'loc': 'loc-002',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Engaged',
          'contact': '--'
        }, {
          'id': 'xxx-003',
          'dev_name': 'rrrrr',
          'department': 'IJK',
          'loc': 'loc-003',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Qued(5)',
          'contact': '--'
        }, {
          'id': 'xxx-004',
          'dev_name': 'bbbbb',
          'department': 'LMN',
          'loc': 'loc-004',
          'hourly_rate': '00',
          'current_Status': 'Vacction',
          'contact': '--'
        }];

        data.forEach(elm => {
           const temp = [elm.id, elm.dev_name, elm.department, elm.loc, elm.hourly_rate, elm.current_Status, elm.contact];
           rows.push(temp);
           console.log('Rows', rows); // showing all data
         });

        downloadPDF.autoTable({
          head: header,
          body: rows,
        });
        downloadPDF.save('demo.pdf');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up. now table generated properly. but cells are not aligned with actual json data. could you pls tell me how apply styles. i've gone through official doc but not able to understand that

Comment: I've downloaded the _demo.pdf_ file. And I see all data are rendered with actual.json. Maybe you have mistake in your code?

Comment: what i mean is, the actual propertie's length of json response from api is too large. example `{'thisIsTheExampleProperties':'The length of the header is too long'}` i want to show the long values in header with properly aligned

Comment: I checked header value with 1000+ symbols and pdf was rendered well (header is about 4 pages). Maybe problem is in another part of your code? Could you create a codepen example please?

Comment: row data are not aligned properly

Comment: You use string concatination instead of using comma
`const temp = [elm.id + elm.dev_name + elm.department + elm.loc + elm.hourly_rate + elm.current_Status + elm.contact];`
replace to 
`const temp = [elm.id, elm.dev_name, elm.department, elm.loc, elm.hourly_rate, elm.current_Status, elm.contact];`

Comment: solution found. i did one very very worst silly mistake in looping. now its working as expected. thank you so much for your solution

Comment: could you pls tell me where to add header/ footer with page number. i spend lot time to achieve that, but failed..! https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqvqVX: